# How to toggle a wishlist button with an Ajax function in Django

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, ajax

So I have run into a bug that is just driving me crazy. When you open my webpage, a list of jobs are provided which have a small heart shaped wishlist icon next to them. Normally, if the job is part of your wishlist it should appear as a red icon, which if you click would have a sweetalert popup that says the job is removed from your wishlist. And if the job is not part of your wishlist it would be displayed in blue, which if you click would have a pop up that says the job has been added to your wishlist. All this works, except for when you have just loaded the page for the **first time**, and one of the listed jobs is **NOT** part of your wishlist, and displayed in blue. If you click this blue icon, instead of saying "added to wishlist" and turning red, it says "removed from wishlist" and stays blue, even though its not part of the wishlist. Clicking the button **AGAIN**, will then do the correct action, saying "added to wishlist" and flipping the color, so the error only occurs the first time. Something wrong with .data('wl') being set for the first time?

But the funny part is, if you load the page for the first time and one of the jobs **IS** part of your wishlist and displayed in **red**, clicking it will do the **correct action**, giving a popup saying it has been removed, and turning the wishlist icon blue - so this error **ONLY** occurs on the first attempt to turn a BLUE icon RED. Any subsequent attempt works fine unless you refresh the page. The error **never** occurs when clicking a wishlisted(RED) job turning it blue, even on the first attempt.

**Side Note**: Please keep in mind I am trying to change the color of the wishlist icon without reloading the page. I've also included an image for context. Thanks!

[Image of job listing page with wishlist icons, red=Remove, blue=Add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWIvr.png)

```js
function addorremove(id) {
        if (id){
        var wishlist= $('#jobwl'+id).data('wl');
        if (wishlist == 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url:"/users/add-wishlist/" +id,
                method:"GET",
                success:function () {
                    $('#jobwl'+id).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-danger')
                    const Toast = Swal.mixin({
                      toast: true,
                      position: 'top-end',
                      showConfirmButton: true,
                      timer: 3000,
                      timerProgressBar: true,
                      didOpen: (toast) => {
                        toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
                        toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
                      }
                    })

                    Toast.fire({
                      icon: 'success',
                      title: 'Added to Wishlist'
                    })
                    $('#jobwl'+id).data('wl',1);


                }
            });
            }else{
                $.ajax({
                    url:"/users/remove-wishlist/" +id,
                    method:"GET",
                    success:function () {
                           $('#jobwl'+id).removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-primary')
                            const Toast = Swal.mixin({
                              toast: true,
                              position: 'top-end',
                              showConfirmButton: true,
                              timer: 3000,
                              timerProgressBar: true,
                              didOpen: (toast) => {
                                toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
                                toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
                              }
                            })

                            Toast.fire({
                              icon: 'success',
                              title: 'Removed from Wishlist'
                            })
                            $('#jobwl'+id).data('wl',0);
                }
            });
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="ml-auto d-flex">
  <a href="{% url 'jobs:single_job' job.slug job.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary py-2 mr-1">Apply Job</a> 
  {% if job.id in wish_list %}
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="jobwl{{ job.id }}" title="Remove from my wishlist" onclick="addorremove({{ job.id }})" class="btn btn-danger rounded-circle btn-favorite d-flex align-items-center">
    <span class="icon-heart"></span>
  </a>
  {% else %}
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="jobwl{{ job.id }}" title="Add to my wishlist" onclick="addorremove({{ job.id }})" class="btn btn-primary rounded-circle btn-favorite d-flex align-items-center">
    <span class="icon-heart"></span>
  </a>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi , what does `var wishlist= $('#jobwl'+id).data('wl');` gives you ?

Comment: In my href I have it set as an id
id="jobwl{{ job.id }}
job.id would be a primary key received from a database

Comment: did you check what exactly `wishlist` has ? `0` or `1` ?